# DIV Auto Re-Loading After Orientation Change

Tags: jquery, responsive

I load my main page menu div with Javascript:

```
$("#main_menu_list").html(mml_html);
```

I also use this Javascript to determine the variable of `mml_html`:

```
var mml_html         = '';
var screen_width     = screen.width;
var screen_height    = screen.height;
if (screen_width < 361)
{
    mml_html += '<ul><li>Item 1</li></ul>';
} else
if (screen_width > 360 && screen_width < 768)
{
    mml_html += '<ul><li>Item 1</li><li>Item 2</li></ul>';
} else
if (screen_width > 767 && screen_width < 1024)
{
    mml_html += '<ul><li>Item 1</li><li>Item 2</li><li>Item 3</li></ul>';
} else
mml_html += '<ul><li>Item 1</li><li>Item 2</li><li>Item 3</li><li>Log In</li></ul>';
```

What I am trying to do is load that menu again, when the device is rotated. On the phone I'm designing on it's 360x640, so when it goes from 360 width to 640 width, I'd like to have the menu show 2 items instead of 1 without refreshing the page.

I tried this code:

```
$(window).on('orientationchange', function() {
    document.body.style.display='none';
    document.body.offsetHeight;             //cause a reflow
    document.body.style.display='block';    //cause a repaint
});
```

But that doesn't appear to do anything. (Maybe I'm doing it wrong, but the jQuery definitely fires off on orientation.)

I have also tried this:

```
$("#main_menu_list").load(location.href+" #main_menu_list>*","");
```

But then the menu list div just goes empty, as if it tried to load but couldn't run the Javascript to rebuild the div data.

Can you not use the `.load` on divs that load from Javascript?

It might work if I put all the code directly on the page instead of having it auto-load through Javascript but I was hoping to have it auto-fill the divs during loading.

Is there a better way to do what I'm trying to do?

I have also thought to just make the menu div a specific size so that it only shows item 1 or item 1 and 2 and just hides the others but that seems like it could cause problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Putting the HTML in the document directly, then hiding or showing parts with CSS Media Queries would be a better solution to this problem.

```css
@media (max-width: 1024px) {
  nav__item:nth-child(4) {
    display: none;  
  }
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  nav__item:nth-child(3) {
    display: none;  
  }
}

@media (max-width: 361px) {
  nav__item:nth-child(2) {
    display: none;  
  }
}
```

```html
<ul class="nav">
  <li clas="nav__item">Item 1</li>
  <li clas="nav__item">Item 2</li>
  <li clas="nav__item">Item 3</li>
  <li clas="nav__item">Log In</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I can't get this to work at all.  I believe that you are correct that @media css Queries are likely my best solution but so far I can't get them to do anything.  I'll keep trying and see if I can figure it out.

Comment: I figured out that it's the "Display: none;" that isn't working.  If I do other things, like change background color, it works great.  But it wont hide.  Can you not hide parts of a list?

Comment: I got it.  I had to add the !IMPORTANT flag to the display: none; for it to override the display: inline; for my menu being horizontal.

Comment: (at)media (max-width: 1024px) {
 .main_nav_menu__item:nth-child(4) 
 {
  display: none !IMPORTANT;  
 }
}
    (at)media (max-width: 768px) {
  .main_nav_menu__item:nth-child(3) 
 {
  display: none !IMPORTANT;  
 }
}
    (at)media (max-width: 360px) {
 .main_nav_menu__item:nth-child(2)
 {
  display: none !IMPORTANT;
 }
}

This was what worked for me finally.  I  marked your answer as the right one.  Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to your custom JS file;

```
var width = screen.width;
var height = screen.height;

setInterval(function () {
    if (screen.width !== width || screen.height !== height) {
        width = screen.width;
        height = screen.height;
        $(window).trigger('resolutionchange');
    }
}, 50);
```

This will detect the screen height/width and if it is not what is expected, it will re-assign then values and trigger a 'resolutionchange' event.

Bind the event as follows:

```
$(window).bind('resolutionchange', function() {
    // code goes here
});
```

OR

```
$(window).bind('resolutionchange', applyResolutionChanges());

resolutionChanges () {
    // Code goes here
}
```

EDIT:
Media queries via CSS would be a better solution in my opinion but this *should* achieve what you are after.